# autostart script with shell interaction

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am seeking to install a script in ubuntu which autoruns when the system reboot.

I have tried running it from /etc/rc.local the problem is:
My script calls a c program which throws some Gtk popups, some printfs in shell and wait for scanf input. When i place it in rc.local and i reboot the system appears to not be executing, but actually  its running in the boot shell background (i see that in /var/log/syslog) so the gtk popups arent able to be shown neither the printf/scanf interaction.

Then i looked for other ways to get that, i found the ~/.config/autostart/
here i place a file.desktop which contains the following:

```
 [Desktop Entry] 
Name=backup Exec=/path/myScript.sh  
Type=Application  
Hidden=false 
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

In myScript i do a make and the following:

> gnome-terminal -e  "bash
>   -c\"/path/myprogram; exec bash\"" &

Finally this is working and this is running when reboot, but the problem now is that my program is being run 2 times one in q new shell (which is exactly what i was looking for) and another in the boot background as it happened with the rc.local method.
What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can use systemd service to autostart a script. The latest version of ubuntu is using systemd services to schedule the scripts. You can find some reference  from /lib/systemd/system directory.

Comment: can you paste the service file which you have created ?

Comment: backup.service:                                                                                            [Unit]
Description=backup service
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/jorge/Documentos/scripts/overwatchSaver/backups/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: you have to enable and start the service using `systemctl enable backup.service` `systemctl start enable.service` after that you can check for the status of your service file `systemctl status enablle.service` . This can give some clue for failure.

Comment: also try changing the Exec start as `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'pathtoyourscript.sh'`